# Spark Structured Streaming Kinesis Data source

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

Is it possible to use Kinesis streams as a data source for Spark structured streaming? I can't find any connector available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qubole have a kinesis-sql library for exactly this.

https://github.com/qubole/kinesis-sql

Then you can use the source similar to any other Spark Structured Streaming source:

```scala
val source = spark
   .readStream
   .format("kinesis")
   .option("streamName", "spark-source-stream")
   .option("endpointUrl", "https://kinesis.us-east-1.amazonaws.com")
   .option("awsAccessKeyId", [YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID])
   .option("awsSecretKey", [YOUR_AWS_SECRET_KEY])
   .option("startingPosition", "TRIM_HORIZON")
   .load
```

Comment: This is still not in production but yea you can use it.
Also I would suggest consume kinesis stream via KCL, once you get Dstreams[ArrayByte] type, convert it to Data frame and load in a temporary view or table. Then you can easily apply sql queries on top of that table.

Comment: @AmanMundra have you tried kcl approach succcesfull?we are getting issue with quobole jar as it is continuously writing empty files